# How to create private Maven Repository (bitbucket) for Android Libraries?

Tags: android, maven, bitbucket

Ok, I've wasted 2 days on researching and googling and still can't find the answer.

### Problem:

I have a couple of libraries, which I would like to share within my company. Currently, they are packed in AAR files. I want to create bitbucket repository, push there my AAR's and use them in future applications in easy way **:** in gradle.build you just need to add `compile "com.mycompanyname.libraryname:version` or something like that.

### Question

Could someone share the detailed guide, please? Becouse I've wasted 2 days researching already=/ I've also found wagon-git plugin, but I've no idea how to use it, since their documentation is quite bad for ppl which are new to maven. Is there must be pom.xml in all my libraries? What if my library depends on another libraries, is it possible to push it into one repository? How to use AAR libraries? A lot of question and literally no answers. Please, any help would be much appreciated.

### P.S

As far as I understood, there must be one pom.xml in repository, and pom.xml in each AAR package. I've tried this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073230/maven-repository-in-three-steps.html). But there are no explanation how to push to bitbucket and how to use AAR artifacts.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this @Rishka?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Repository Manager. Have a look [here](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) about what it means and what managers are out there. I would recommend Sonatype's Nexus. Gradle works with any of these.
Whether you can achieve something similar with just a Bitbucket repository I couldn't say.

Comment: That's actually isn't what i'm looking for=( As far as I understood, nexus hosts local repositories? Or on custom server. But I want to publish my libraries to bitbucket and compile dependecies from there

Comment: So what you're looking for is something like jitpack
https://jitpack.io/docs/PRIVATE/
But I'm assuming free/opesource?

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy to set up private maven repository but also not that much tough, Here is the example check it out [setup-private-maven-repository](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-setup-private-maven-repository/en)